# call function not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey guys am new to javascript and i have seen a function called `call()` in javascript ..I wrote a code of mine to check how `call()` function works ..

My code is

```
(function(baby) { 
console.log(baby);
}).call("oops");
```

When i call the function like this am getting the output like `undefined`..What i need to get output as `oops`.Hope you guys can help me out in getting the desired output by this method ..

Any help would be appreciated ..Thanks a lot in advance ..

Comment: Because that is not how call works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [first parameter of call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is the `this` object, in other words the object that `this` will refer to within the function.

The remaining parameters will be used as the function parameters.  So, what you'd want is:

```
(function(baby) { 
console.log(baby);
}).call(this, "oops");
```

Or..

```
(function(baby) { 
console.log(baby);
}).call(window, "oops");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(function(baby) { 
console.log(baby);
}("oops"));
```

or

```
(function(baby) { 
console.log(baby);
}).call(window, "oops");
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the call method is a "this" for the call and just the second and the rest are passed as arguments to the function. Use .call(null,"oops") and it will work